# MVC Authentication Microsoft, Google, Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, azure

I am sorry for the potential duplication here, but I am a bit confused.

I would like to integrate at least these external authentication providers in a new MVC web site: Microsoft Live ID, Google and Facebook. I realize there are multiple threads concerning this, but I also guess there is continuous improvement in this area. So far I have found it a bit complicated to accomplish. I heard someone mention there is an Azure service helping out with this, but I only found it in the Mobile services. Would that be possible to use in web?

What is the easiest and fastest way to achieve this? Is there an MVC template? Is there a Nuget library? Is there an Azure service?

Comment: The keyword that you're looking for is "OAuth".

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Azure Access Control Service. It provides in-built authentication against these 3 services you are interested in.

Comment: In MVC 5 it's integrated when creating a new project.

Comment: MVC5 integration looks great!!! It might be worth the trouble to redesign my site in MVC5 to get this feature. I removed MVC4-tag ...

Comment: Gauriv, I never heard of ACS. It never crossed my mind to look for external integration in Active Directory service. What would be the benefits of using that as opposed to the suggested MVC5 integration?

Comment: ACS also supports social logins. The advantage is that it is a service so you don't have to worry about the implementation authentication yourself (you could use DotNetOpenAuth as well). Given that your inclination is towards MVC 5, I would not recommend using ACS. There are many reasons ... primarily being no work has been done there in ages + I could not find a way to extend it to support other login providers (e.g. Twitter). For our MVC 4 project, we started with this but then ended up using DotNetOpenAuth. We dumped DotNetOpenAuth when we switched the application to MVC 5. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, exactly the kind of balanced advice that I need!

Answer (score 0):

The default MVC templates include OAuth support out of the box, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement using the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) package.

In the Package Manager console:

> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth

I'm afraid I don't know where to go from there myself, but here's a Github repository with a bunch of samples to get you started: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples

Comment: I was hesitant as I read several people having issues with DotNetOpenAuth library.

Comment: If you're using MVC5, then there's really no need to use DotNetOpenAuth library. As @Complexity mentioned, social logins for at least the 3 providers you're interested in is baked in into MVC template.

Comment: Haven't looked at the MVC5 templates yet. What library does it use if not DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: It makes use of OWIN.

Comment: Here's a nice blogpost about OWIN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx